# Google Ads API - permission

Tags: api, ads, google-ads-api

Is there a way to allow the Google Ads API token to perform only the following operation:

- adding IP addresses on all campains blacklist.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there's no possibility to restrict the privileges, neither for a given Ads API developer token nor by using specific OAuth2 scopes (there's only [a single one](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/api/docs/oauth/internals#scope) for the whole Ads API).

An OAuth2 access token will reflect the permissions of the granting user, so what you *can do* is to create an access token that does have [read-only access to a given Ads account](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/9978556). But this does not solve your specific use case.